# Extract keypair from hd wallet address and use for signing/verifying via libsodium

Tags: wallet, private-key, public-key, library

I like to use priv/pub keypair of an hd wallet address to sign/verfify data (outside a transaction signment). Based on this [question](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/7424/how-to-derive-non-extended-skey-from-mnemonic-phrase/7428#7428) i know how to derive the private key out of an address and i assume to get the public key via:

```
./cardano-address key inspect <<< $(cat public.key)
```

and then use the 'extended_key' value.

I try to verify the extracted keypair via libsodium:

```
sign:     libsodium.crypto_sign(message, sender_secret_ed25519)
verify:   libsodium.crypto_sign_open(signed_message, sender_pubkey_ed25519)
```

and fail to verify a signed message.

I think i may use the wrong public and/or private key or i need to convert the keys somehow.

does anyone have a recommendation to get this working?